# Why is my component not re-rendering after updating it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, axios

I'm trying to change state of my array of objects, it does change state, but my component isn't re-rendering. Why is that?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(data && data.rows) {
        data.rows.forEach(async (elem) => {
            const row = await axios.get(url);
            elem.members= row.data.length;
        })
    }
}, [data])
```

Answer (score 1):

component will re-render only when you set state whether it's class based component or hooks

1.class based component `this.setState()`

2.hooks `setLen()`

```
const [len, setLen] = React.useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    if(data && data.rows) {
        data.rows.forEach(async (elem) => {
            const row = await axios.get(url);
            setLen(row.data.length);
        })
    }
}, [data])
```

Comment: You're setting state on each loop iteration, which will cause multiple renders.

Comment: You're changing single state, that's not what i meant

Comment: @Ralph are you changing state value in loop ?

Comment: I'm changing single object property in a loop. It works, but it doesn't re-render

Answer (score 0):

For a component to re render the state must be updated. You need to do the `setState` for your component to update. Also if you are getting the updated values from props then you should consider using `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook of react.